# SkMaps Remove SKPolylines

Tags: android, polyline, skmaps

Currently I am removing `SKPolylines` by tracking their `setIdentifier(int)` numbers when I create them, and then when I delete them I apply a new polyline to the map with the same identifier that is transparent. I have two issues with this:

1. I assume there should be a way to do `mapView.removePolyline(int identifier);` or `mapView.removeAllPolylines();`
2. I also assume there should be a way to do `mapView.getAllPolylines()` that returns a `List<SKPolyine>` because that is possible with POI's and annotations. At the very least `mapView.getNumPolylines();` that returns the number of polylines so that I can delete them all with my original method, without having to track how many I have put down.

My question is: Am I missing either functionality described in 1/2? If those functionalities do not exist then is there a better way than my current method?

Comment: Unfortunately, those functionalities do not exist. Alternative for 2: SKMapSurfaceView.SKDrawingOrder: http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.5.0/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKMapSurfaceView.SKDrawingOrder.html

Comment: @Sylvia That documentation is either incorrect or out of date... Seems it should be `SKMapSettings.SKDrawingOrderType` and there isn't any explanation of how I should use it. If you provide one as an answer to this question I will accept it.

Comment: sorry- indeed it was a change in the latest build: http://developer.skobbler.ro/changelog/android/2.5.1